# Configuring Swagger to ignore Spring Boot Actuator endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot RESTful web service & Swagger 2 here. I have the following `@Configuration` class setup to configure Swagger for my service:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
    }
}
```

I start my service and then I go to `http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs` (where Swagger is served from) and then paste that JSON into [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) and I see that Spring Boot is adding roughly ~40 endpoints automatically that I **do not want** Swagger to document. Things like the `/trace` endpoint, and `/health`, `/env` and `/beans`, etc. These are all things Spring Boot Actuator creates but that I don't want included in my public API documentation.

**Is there a way to configure Swagger to *not* document these framework-level endpoints?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `any()` will make documentation for your entire API available through Swagger. Use `PathSelectors.ant()` to limit your endpoints. 
Something like

`.paths(PathSelectors.ant("/finance/**"))`  will only display endpoints under `/finance/`

Answer (score 5):

```
RequestHandlerSelectors.any()
```

will expose all the endpoints of your project.

On top of above answer, You can add use below code to restrict the exposure of API by providing your base package name in **RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage()** method.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
      .select()                                  
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.assingment.scalableweb"))
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
      .build()
      .apiInfo(metaData())
      .tags(new Tag("DifferenceController", "Operations related to the Json Data")); 
}
```